# List bullets have more spacing in Mozilla and IE than in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, mozilla

[image: This is when viewed in Google Chrome, updated to date.]

[image: This is when viewed in Mozilla, updated to date.]

[image: This is when viewed in Internet Explorer, updated to date.]

Below is my HTML:

```
<div id="text_style">
<div id="text_style_in">
<ul>
    <li>
    <p><a href="#" target="_self">Fact Sheet</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <p><a href="#" target="_self">Facilities and Administrative (F&amp;A) Cost Agreements</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <p><a href="#" target="_self">PropStart</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <p><a href="#" target="_self">Equipment Matching</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <p><a href="#" target="_self">Training Guide: Preparing Research Proposal Budgets</a></p>
    </li>
    <li>
    <p><a href="#" target="_self">Three Work-Day Rule</a></p>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I have no list style defined uniquely.
How can I make the list look similar in Mozilla and IE?

Comment: I want to keep <p > tag, its my text style.
Is there any other way ..?

Comment: you can add that textstyle to your list <li> tag

Comment: Yes, I guess I'll have to do that, I was hoping that there would be some way out to do that without removing the <p> tag.
thanks for your time and help.

Comment: The <p> tag is a block, so most of the times it starts on a new line. Give the <li> tags a class and put your style in that class

Comment: If you need another element to target with CSS, add a span. It'll have less baggage from the browser's stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete de `<p>` tag, and make it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" target="_self">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_self">two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `<p>` element nested into each `<li>` element into your html.

You have instead to write:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" target="_self">Fact Sheet</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self">Facilities and Administrative (F&A) Cost Agreements</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self">PropStart</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self">Equipment Matching</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self">Training Guide: Preparing Research Proposal Budgets</a></li>
<li><a href="#" target="_self">Three Work-Day Rule</a></li>
</ul>
```

But if you want to simply keep the `<p>` elements. make them inline-block with: `ul li p {display: inline-block}` and lines should not break...